# How can I make several divs on the left overlap one div on the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a horizontal bargraph in CSS. The bars on the bargraph could be one long one or one long one with 4 smaller rectangles attached to the end of the longer bar. However I want there to also be a bar coming in from the right that's long.

When there is four smaller bars attached the end of the long one or when the long one is so long it overlaps the bar on the right, I want the bars on the left to overlap on top of the bar on the right. Currently, it pushes down the content and does not overlap. I want it to overlap (not push down the content).

How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
//Bars on the left 
    div.leftbar, div.post, div.static, div.value{height:24px; float:left;position:absolute;}

    div.post1, div.post2, div.post3 {height:24px; float:left;}

    div.post4 {height:24px; float:left;}

//Bar on the right
div.rightbar {height:24px; float:right; z-index:-1;}

.leftbar{background: #4c8fe1;}

.post1{
    background: #1D93C3;
}
.post2{

    background: #2EB0E5;
}
.post3{

    background: #66C4EA;
}
.post4{

    background: #A2DAF1;

//html: 
<div class="leftbar" style="width:31.25%"></div>
<div class="post1" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post2" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post3" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post4" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="rightbar" style="width:53%;"></div>
```

One thing to note above is position absolute works if I don't have the other four divs after the left bar. They don't appear on the graph at all if i set position: absolute but if I set position:absolute and those four divs are 0. The overlapping works. I need the overlapping to work for both scenarios.

I've attached a horibbly drawn image to illustrate what I mean. 
[image]

Basically, I currently have the above if the either the left or right bar are not too long. Once either is too long, the divs gets pushed down.

I want the left side of the bargraph to overlap the right side always such that if the blue bar on the right extends further left.... the left bars are on top of the blue bar.

Comment: move them! lol j/k but for real, move them ... using css! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your rightbar a large negative margin:

```css
div.leftbar,
div.post,
div.static,
div.value {
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
}
div.post1,
div.post2,
div.post3 {
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
}
div.post4 {
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
}
div.rightbar {
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  position: relative; /* <-------------- needed for z-index */
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -100%; /* <--------------------- margin here */
  background: pink;
}
.leftbar {
  background: #4c8fe1;
}
.post1 {
  background: #1D93C3;
}
.post2 {
  background: #2EB0E5;
}
.post3 {
  background: #66C4EA;
}
.post4 {
  background: #A2DAF1;
}
```

```html
<p>
<div class="leftbar" style="width:31.25%"></div>
<div class="post1" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post2" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post3" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post4" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="rightbar" style="width:53%;"></div>
</p>
<br>
<p>
<div class="leftbar" style="width:31.25%"></div>
<div class="post1" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post2" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post3" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="post4" style="width:5%;"></div>
<div class="rightbar" style="width:13%;"></div>
</p>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/umyb400p/)**

Comment: This works nicely, Is it any catch to using a negative margin?

Comment: Only that some developers are snobby about it. :)

Comment: To clarify, negative margins can be a crutch for "fixing" bad layouts. Used sparingly, they're a powerful and well-supported mechanism.

Comment: What does it mean exactly to have a negative margin?

Comment: It simply allows for overlap. In some cases, the element with negative margin moves. In others, nearby content is allowed to intrude on the element's space.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @isherwood Wow... I find that explanation scanty at best: The DOM flows left-to-right, top-to-bottom, meaning all elements are naturally pushing towards the top left corner of the screen.  Thus, elements with negative top/left margins will shift in those directions, while elements with negative bottom/right margins will cause elements after them (that are pushing towards the top left) to shift to the top/left respectively.

Comment: By all means, feel free to de-scant the situation. No need to call me out, though, just because I'm not inclined to write entire guidebooks in comments. :)

Comment: You seem to understand that many developers might disagree with your answer.  To protect you from future downvotes, I was hoping to prompt you to explain to the OP and your 'snobby developers' why your answer works (and it does work, being a perfectly valid--and actually clever--use of negative margins).  Your 7 words of explanation in your answer can hardly be considered sufficient.  But I'll leave the explaining to you.

Answer (score 0):

don't float!

// css

```
.postcontainer { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 24px 
}
.leftbar {
    display: inline-block; 
    z-index: 2;
}
.rightbar {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    top:0px; 
    bottom: 0px
    z-index: 1;
}
.post {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

// html

```
<div class="postcontainer">
    <div class="leftbar" style="width: 31.25%;"></div>
    <div class="rightbar" style="width: 53%;"></div>
    <div class="post post1"></div>
    <div class="post post2"></div>
    <div class="post post3"></div>
    <div class="post post4"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I added an image to my post. Please see

Comment: You should use an embedded snippet demo or provide an external demo.

Answer (score 0):

Using inline-block to get rid of float is nice. Also get rid of style tags in the html just for preference.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.leftbar,
.post1,
.post2,
.post3,
.post4,
.rightbar {
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px
}

.post1,
.post2,
.post3,
.post4 {
  width: calc((50% - (100%/3))/ 4)
}

.leftbar {
  background: #4c8fe1;
  width: calc(100%/3)
}

.post1 {
  background: #1D93C3
}

.post2 {
  background: #2EB0E5
}

.post3 {
  background: #66C4EA
}

.post4 {
  background: #A2DAF1
}

.rightbar {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ff0
}
```

```html
<div class="leftbar"></div>
<div class="post1"></div>
<div class="post2"></div>
<div class="post3"></div>
<div class="post4"></div>
<div class="rightbar"></div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/zb0k1rkr/)**

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to avoid Overqualify and Chaining

```
// bad
ul#someid {..}
.menu#otherid {..}
div.classname {..}

// good
#someid {..}
#otherid {..}
.classname {..}
```

and second suggestion is to use `id` to identify unique elements.

Now let's answer your question:

The idea is to set `position: absolute;` and `right: 0` to `.rightbar`, at this point the bar will be in the right, so use `z-index` to overlap the left bars.

Try this:

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bar{
    height: 24px;
}

.left-bars{
    float:left;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.leftbar{background: #4c8fe1;}

#post1{
    background: #1D93C3;
}
#post2{

    background: #2EB0E5;
}
#post3{

    background: #66C4EA;
}
#post4{
    background: #A2DAF1;
}
.rightbar{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #54ff4e;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar left-bars leftbar" style="width:31.25%"></div>
    <div id="post1" class="bar left-bars" style="width:5%;"></div>
    <div id="post2" class="bar left-bars" style="width:5%;"></div>
    <div id="post3" class="bar left-bars" style="width:5%;"></div>
    <div id="post4" class="bar left-bars" style="width:5%;"></div>
    <div class="bar rightbar" style="width:53%;"></div>
</div>
```